# How to get rid of certain characters in a string on mips assembly

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I was wondering if someone could help explain to me how to get rid of specific characters in a string on mips.
For example, if the string is "+104367"
and I want to get rid of the +, and have simply: 104367.

Comment: Given you've not described the types of matching you want. I would say make a pen and paper list of example edits you want to support and then one character and a time "process them" on paper then code your hand algorithm up in the ASM of the day.

Comment: could you give me an example code of how to iterate through a string?
what I have in mind is..

Comment: la    $t0, someString





 
                            lw    $s3, 0($t0)        #someString[0]

               addi  $s3, $zero, 1      #someString[1]


given that pseudo code, and lets say the someString is "+104367" how would calculate the address of the + symbol? Am I doing it right?

Comment: Run the code, see what happens. That's how you check and debug code, not by asking at SO.

Comment: Obviously the code isn't working if I'm asking a question on here :P

Comment: The reason for my question are, you siad "specific characters" doe that mean "all +" or "all + and &" or does it mean "the first symbol" like in your example.

Comment: I was simply asking a generic question. I even provided a basic example. I was basically asking how to remove characters from a string so I could apply it to my assignment without cheating. Regardless, I have a found a solution

Comment: If you have found a solution consider sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .data
    str:  .asciiz "Hello+World"

 .text  
 main:  
    la $t0, str  # la means load address (so we load the address of str into $t0)  
    li $t1, 0    # $t1 is the counter. set it to 0  

    la $t3, 43   # 43 is ASCII of '+' in DEC
 countChr:  
    lb $t2, 0($t0)  # Load the first byte from address in $t0  
    beqz $t2, end   # if $t2 == 0 then go to label end
    bne $t2, $t3, proceed   # branch if symbol equals 43 (+)
    la $t4, $t0 # save the position
proceed:  
    add $t0, 1      # else increment the address  
    add $t1, $t1, 1 # and increment the counter of course  

    j countChr      # finally loop  


 end:  
    # Do whatever you want here.  
    # Just remember that the length of the string is stored in $t1
    # Here you have the position of '+' saved to t4
```